# RTF template coding, XSLT coding

Tags: templates, xslt, rtf

I have the below requirement

```
<data>
<dataset1>
     <number>1</number>
     <name>red</name>
     <number>2</number>
     <name>Yellow</name>
     <number>3</number>
     <name>black</name>
     <number>4</number>
     <name>Violet</name> 
</dataset1>

<dataset2>
     <index>1</index>
     <index>2</index>
     <index>3</index>
     <index>4</index>
</dataset2>
</data>
```

I need to loop through dataset2 take the index value, compare it with the value of number tag in dataset1. If a match occurs then display value of corresponding name tag. I need to get the output in rtf format. Please give BI tags or relevent xslt code to do the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: not even close to a real question...

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and re-write your question. Please include your progress so far.

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kNameByNumber"
             match="name"
             use="preceding-sibling::number[1]"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="index[key('kNameByNumber',.)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' : ',key('kNameByNumber',.),'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
1 : red
2 : Yellow
3 : black
4 : Violet
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the RTF format so I can't help with outputting that format, however below is an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that processes the `dataset2/index` elements and outputs any matching "dataset1/name`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="dataset1/name" use="preceding-sibling::number[1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/dataset2/index"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dataset2/index">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Index: ', .,
                                 '; match: ', key('k1', .), '&#10;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So with your sample the output is

```
Index: 1; match: red
Index: 2; match: Yellow
Index: 3; match: black
Index: 4; match: Violet
```

Comment: OP wrote *If a match occurs then display value*